# PhoneGap - Icon / Spashscreen Size cycling through sizes with every build

Tags: cordova, icons, splash-screen

I've been working on something else and going through several builds using PhoneGap 3.0 and PhoneGap build. On this process I started noticing that the icon size and the splash screen size were cycling through the various sizes in the resources folder (e.g. one time we get ldpi the next mdpi and so on through the sizes). The icon and splash screen don't always use the same size either, one can be small the other large and vice versa.

Has anyone seen this before? This only started happening this evening and no changes have been made that effect the splash screen or the icon in fact I haven't touched the config.xml for weeks.

Any ideas on what might be causing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. It appears that if you don't have a icon and image size for xxhdpi (notice that has two xx's) then things tend to go a bit haywire.

So adding an xxhdpi icon sized 144 x 144
and a xxhdpi spalsh screen sized a 3 times the size of the mdpi

Remember to put in links in your config.xml file.